# Creating application that might be installed not from Play Store

Tags: android, android-studio

I have created GUI application with Android Studio that runs fine emulator. I have build it by pressing `Build->Generate signed bundle/apk` I have placed this application in download page in order to download and install by using my phone.

I have downloaded application and started installation. Got message:

```
Do you want to install this application? It does not require special access.
```

Press `install` button.

Got message

```
App not installed.
```

How to know reason why it is not installed?

Comment: it is quite hard to know that. Do you have it's debug version installed already?

Answer (score 3):

try with Disabling `Play Protect` option in Play store app

To disable Google Play Protect.

- Open "Play Store" application
- tap on Menu button
- select "Play Protect" option
- Disable the options "Scan device for security threats".

Comment: @Abbas it would not allow even to start installation without that option enabled. Your comment does not relate to the answer itself.

Comment: @Abbas please stop leaving unrelated comments. If you have alternative solution - post your own answer, or at least **comment the question**, not the answer that is not related to your comments.

Comment: This answer worked on Samsung Galaxy S8 SM-G950U1, when installing APK via Samsung > My Files  > Internal Storage > Downloads > filename.apk